# MatrixForm in Mathematica

Tags: matrix

I wanted to do subtractions between to matrices and I did the following

```
A = {{.96, .04, 0, 0}, {0, .94, .06, 0}, {0, 0, .94, .06}, {0, 0, 
   0, .96}}

B = IdentityMatrix[4] - A // MatrixForm
```

I got what I wanted. But if I did

```
A = {{.96, .04, 0, 0}, {0, .94, .06, 0}, {0, 0, .94, .06}, {0, 0, 
   0, .96}} // MatrixForm

B = IdentityMatrix[4] - A // MatrixForm
```

I got a mess.

Could anybody explain why such difference exists?

Comment: `MatrixForm` acts as a "wrapper", which affects printing, but not evaluation. Further calculations can't be done with a matrix if you apply `MatrixForm` on it's definition. It is just a function to pretty print or visualize a matrix in Mathematica.

Comment: See in particular [point 8 in this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/245)

Comment: Unless you evaluate in place. I have an example in [MatrixFormDivided](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MatrixFormDivided/) (Possible Issues section)